# Load JSON file from header without Ajax

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list of specific states I want to load into a dropdown list on page load. Because of this I don't have the need for AJAX and thus want to avoid it. How can I access the json file within my page load?

This is what I have.

My JSON file contains:

```
[{"States":{"AL" : "Alabama", "AK" : "Alaska", "WI" : "Wisconsin", "WY" : "Wyoming" }}]
```

How I load it onto my HTML header.

```
<script type="application/json" src="mystates.json"></script>
```

How can I access the above with Javascript?

Comment: [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't think you need `type="application/json"`, you can use `type="text/javascript"`.  I think your script will be there on the page, but it's not assigned to anything, so you have a couple of options.  1.  Set it equal to something:  `var json = ...`.  2.  pass it to a function.

Comment: If I there's flexibility to modify `mystates.json`, I'd modify it to look into look like: `preExistingJSFunction([{"States":{..}..}])`. Google for JSONP. It's much similar to your usage of script tag. :)

Comment: Thanks Tim. But how would I be able to tell my javascript json variable to use the embeded json/js file? I've seen examples where people hardcode the json into the javascript but I want to use the separate file.

Comment: .. Or the other option is to have your server side side script inject the contents of the JSON file into a JS variable in script tag area of your HTML. That way, you can still have it as a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put my comments as answer here.

Using AJAX is the easiest way in case like these, esp. using `$.getJSON(..)` as @mavili suggested.

If you are unwilling to have an async request, you have two options(in my opinion, YMMV :) )

- Have a Javascript function, which takes in one parameter like:

  ```
  function saveStates(statesObject) {
     /* store states here */
  }
  ```

  and  then have your states JSON file modified to look like this:

  ```
  saveStates([{"States":{"AL" : "Alabama", "AK" : "Alaska", ..}..}])
  ```

  Now, simply include this file as you'd usually do in your HTML.
- Or the other option is have your server side script read the the file contents and inject the contents into the HTML (javascript `<script>` area).

In both of the approaches your JSON file can be separately changed.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Took me a bit because I had my function declared after the json file was attached.